# How to associate model to another model by two foreignKeys ? (in sequelize)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Let's imagine situation

You have two models:
**event_user** with attributes: *id*
**event_user_message** with attributes: *user_from_id, user_to_id*

**You want to get *20* event_users that were in contact (by message/s) with user X**

**definition of associations**

```
EventUser.hasMany(eventUserMessages, as: "from", foreignKey: "user_from_id")
EventUser.hasMany(eventUserMessages, as: "to", foreignKey: "user_to_id")

EventUserMessages.belongsTo(eventUser, as: "from", foreignKey: "user_from_id")
EventUserMessages.belongsTo(eventUser, as: "to", foreignKey: "user_to_id")
```

**Solution 1**
*problem*: *in this case I get only users that had two ways conversation*

var include, limit, where;
limit = parameters.limit ? parameters.limit : 20;

```
include.push({
  model: models.eventUserMessages,
  as: "to",
  where: {user_from_id: parameters.inConnectionWith}
  attributes: []
});

include.push({
  model: models.eventUserMessages,
  as: "from",
  where: {user_to_id: parameters.inConnectionWith}
  attributes: []
});

eventUserModel.findAll({
  include: include,
  where: where
})
```

**Solution 2**
In this solution you get all expected result
*problem*: *in this solutions is you can not use Limit (does not work)*

```
include.push({
  model: models.eventUserMessages,
  as: "to",
  required: false,
  attributes: []
});

include.push({
  model: models.eventUserMessages,
  as: "from",
  required: false,
  attributes: []
});

where = Sequelize.and(where, Sequelize.or({
  "to.user_from_id": parameters.inConnectionWith
}, {
  "from.user_to_id": parameters.inConnectionWith
}));

eventUserModel.findAll({
  include: include,
  where: where
})
```

will appreciate if you provide some suggestions about how to achieve this

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your got yourself confused. In your 1st solution, by doing:

```
include.push({
  model: models.eventUserMessages,
  as: "to",
  where: {user_from_id: parameters.inConnectionWith}
  attributes: []
});
```

You are essentially making a join on `EventUser.id = EventUserMessages.user_to_id WHERE EventUserMessages.user_from_id = parameters.inConnectionWith`.

The join has already curtailed your result set to those containing `user_to_id = parameters.inConnectionWith`. Your `where` criteria then curtails the result further down to `user_to_id = parameters.inConnectionWith`

This gave you the result of returning users with 2 way communication. If you don't understand why, look at my answer below:

```
include.push({
  model: models.eventUserMessages,
  as: "to",

  //firstly, you don't need this.
  //Secondly, if anything, it should be user_to_id, which won't do anything.
  /* where: {user_to_id: parameters.inConnectionWith} */ 

  attributes: []
});
```

However, using includes in this situation is not required if your dataset does not require attributes from the `event_user` table. Take those out and your solution 1 should work fine.

It is far more efficient to run the query suggested below:

```
EventUserMessages.findAll({
    where: Sequelize.or(
        { user_from_id: parameters.inConnectionWith },
        { user_to_id: parameters.inConnectionWith }
    },
    limit: 20,
    order: [ you need to order them so you will return the relevant 20 datasets ]
});
```